# How to check the element of list string variable

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I wanted to write a simple system via the list, that will recognize symbols and do a bit of calculation of some symbols inside the list, and will tell if there are any of mistakes.

And it looks like this:

```
private static List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
private static void splitToList(String string){

    list.addAll(Arrays.asList("((35+6-(4+4))=0;".split("")));
    chekList(list);
}
private static void chekList (List list){
    int open = 0;
    int close =0;

    for (int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
       System.out.println(list.get(i));
        if (list.get(i) == "(") {
            open++;
            System.out.println(open);
        }
        if (list.get(i) == ")") {
            close++;
            System.out.println(close);
        }

    }
    if (open != close){
        System.out.println("false!");
        br = true;
    }

}
```

So the problem that this if statements for recognize "(" and ")" in list element does not work anyhow. Is there is any way to check my list element for being "(" or ")"?

Here is a full IDE output. Without any of "open" and "close" results.

[image: Here is a full IDE output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`==` tests for reference equality (whether they are the same object).

You need to use `")".equals(list.get(i))` to test for value equality (whether they are logically "equal").

Answer (score 1):

```
private static void chekList (List<String> list){
    int open = 0;
    int close =0;

    for(String str : list) {
        System.out.println(str);

        if ("(".equals(str))
            System.out.println(++open);
        else if (")".equals(str))
            System.out.println(++close);
    }

    if (open != close)
        System.out.println("false!");
}
```